# Como puedo pasar un objeto knockout.js observablearray a MVC Controller en ASP.Net MVC 5

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc, knockoutjs

Estoy tratando de llamar un método utilizando knockout js, pero no me funciona, estoy mostrando el listado de los prestamos y en el detalle del préstamo muestro una tabla de amortización con los pagos que se deben realizar a dicho préstamo, pero cuando hago click en el botón no me funciona.

Probé el método, fuera de la tabla de amortización y funciona perfectamente, pero cuando quiero que selecionar una cuota para pagarla quiero traer ese modelo para realizar el pago, pero no me funciona, este es el codigo que tengo hasta el momento.

Este es el codigo html con knockout js:

```
<div id="divDetailLoans" data-bind="visible: IsDetails">
    <div class="form-horizontal" data-bind="with: LoanModel">
        <div>
            <h3><strong>Detalles</strong></h3>
            <br />
            <dl class="dl-horizontal">
                <dt>
                    <strong>No. Prestamo:</strong>
                </dt>

                <dd>
                    <span style="text-align:left" data-bind="text: CodeLoan"></span>
                </dd>
                <dt>
                    <strong>Cliente:</strong>
                </dt>

                <dd>
                    <span style="text-align:left" data-bind="text: FullName"></span>
                </dd>
                <dt>
                    <strong>Monto del Prestamo:</strong>
                </dt>

                <dd>
                    <span style="text-align:left" data-bind="text: Amount"></span>
                </dd>
                <dt>
                    <strong>Monto Pendiente:</strong>
                </dt>

                <dd>
                    <span style="text-align:left" data-bind="text: AmountCurrent"></span>
                </dd>
                <dt>
                    <strong>Tasa:</strong>
                </dt>

                <dd>
                    <span style="text-align:left" data-bind="text: Rate"></span><span>%</span>
                </dd>
                <dt>
                    <strong>Interes Generado:</strong>
                </dt>

                <dd>
                    <span style="text-align:left" data-bind="text: Interest"></span>
                </dd>
                <dt>
                    <strong>Interes Ganado:</strong>
                </dt>

                <dd>
                    <span style="text-align:left" data-bind="text: InterestAmount"></span>
                </dd>
                <dt>
                    <strong>Fecha:</strong>
                </dt>

                <dd>
                    <span style="text-align:left" data-bind="text: DateCreation"></span>
                </dd>
                <dt>
                    <strong>Ciclo de Prestamo:</strong>
                </dt>
                <dd>
                    <span style="text-align:left" data-bind="text: CycleLoanName"></span>
                </dd>
                <dt>
                    <strong>Tipo de Prestamo:</strong>
                </dt>
                <dd>
                    <span id="QuantityQuotasDetEdit" style="text-align:left" data-bind="text: TypeLoanName"></span>
                </dd>
                <dt id="QuantityQuotasDet">
                    <strong>No. Cuotas:</strong>
                </dt>
                <dd>
                    <span id="QuantityQuotasDetItem" style="text-align:left" data-bind="text: QuantityQuota"></span>
                </dd>
                <dt>
                    <strong>Estado de Prestamo:</strong>
                </dt>

                <dd>
                    <span style="text-align:left" data-bind="text: StateLoanName"></span>
                </dd>
                <dt>
                    <strong>Nota:</strong>
                </dt>

                <dd>
                    <span style="text-align:left" data-bind="text: Note"></span>
                </dd>
            </dl>
        </div>
        <div id="divListAmortizationTables">
            <hr />
            <h3>Tabla de Amortizacion</h3>
            <table class="table">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>
                            No. Cuota
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            Valor Cuota
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            Capital
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            Interes
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            Fecha
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            Estado
                        </th>

                        <th></th>
                        <th></th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody data-bind="foreach: $parent.AmortizationTable">
                    <tr>
                        <td style="text-align:left" data-bind="text: NumberQuota"></td>
                        <td style="text-align:left" data-bind="text: AmountPay.toFixed(2)"></td>
                        <td style="text-align:left" data-bind="text: AmountCapital.toFixed(2)"></td>
                        <td style="text-align:left" data-bind="text: AmountInterest.toFixed(2)"></td>
                        <td style="text-align:left" data-bind="text: moment(DatePayment).format('DD/MM/YYYY') "></td>
                        <td style="text-align:left" data-bind="text: StatePayName"></td>
                        <td style="text-align:center">
                            <a href="#" data-bind="click: $parent.PayQuota" class=" btn btn-success">Pagar</a>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Este es el codigo javascript que estoy utilizando,

```
loanViewModel.PayQuota = function (model) {
    swal({
        title: "Esta seguro?",
        text: "Que desea pagar esta cuota?",
        type: "warning",
        showCancelButton: true,
        confirmButtonClass: "btn-success",
        confirmButtonText: "Si",
        cancelButtonText: "Cancelar",
        closeOnConfirm: false,
        closeOnCancel: false
    },
        function (isConfirm) {
            if (isConfirm) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: '/AdminAmortizationTables/PayQuota',
                    data: ko.toJSON(model),
                    dataType: "json",
                    type: "POST",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    async: true,
                    success: function (data) {
                        if (data.Success) {
                            swal("Pagado!", "Se ha realizado el pago satisfactoriamente", "success");
                        }
                        else {
                            swal("Error realizando el pago!", data.Data, "error")
                        }
                    }
                });

            } else {
                swal("Cancelado!", "El pago no ha sido realizado", "error");
            }
        });
};
```

Por lo que quiero obtener es si seleciono la cuota no 1 por ejemplo quiero que en el modelo me traiga esos datos.

Comment: ¿El título es una pregunta o es una afirmación?

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster es una pregunta

Comment: ¿Tu pregunta es si puedes ejecutar el metodo click en knockout js ASP.Net MVC 5?

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster no creo que sea asi porque se que se puede porque lo he hecho, lo que pasa es que en el mentodo click de kcnockout js, no me esta funcionando ese metodo, y por eso quiero saber si alguien me puede ayudar con eso, por eso en el titulo coloco el metodo para que entiendan la pregunta

Comment: Entonces el título es una afirmación, no una pregunta.

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster pero puedes ayudarme con la pregunta?

Comment: Yo no tengo conocimiento suficiente para responder, pero espero que alguien de la página sí lo tenga ¡te deseo suerte!